# How to Let Drools’ `from` Conditional Element Return a Collection?

Tags: drools

How to let the [conditional element `from`](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.3.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch08.html#d0e10124) return a complete collection in Drools?

Unfortunately the conditional element works specially for collections on the “expression” (i.e., right) side of the `from` element. Take these rules as an example, where only the `test String` rule fires although I want only the `test Set` rule to fire:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Collections;

function Set testFunction() {
    return Collections.singleton("FOO");
}

rule "test Set"
when
    $s : Set() from testFunction()
then
    System.out.println($s);
end

rule "test String"
when
    $s : String() from testFunction()
then
    System.out.println($s);
end
```

I don’t want to call the function twice and I don’t want to change the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to collect the elements of your Set in another collection using a `from collect` or `from accumulate` construct.

```
rule "test Set"
when
    $s : Set() from collect(String() from testFunction())
then
    System.out.println($s);
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: +1, thanks! In the meantime I have come up with the exact same approach, actually :-)  However, I’m unsure if that’s really a good solution or just a workaround: essentially, the (possibly large) set which is returned by the function is duplicated for no good reason. I would prefer to directly use the set returned from the function instead of having to re-create it.

Comment: Well, if you are not planning to add any constraint to your set nor use it as part of another constraint (basically, you just want to use it in the right hand side of your rules) then you can just invoke the function straight in the action part of the rule.

Comment: Unfortunately my rules are not as simple as the example here. Amongst others, I have a `not( Foo( barSet == $s ) )` condition on the LHS, i.e., I can’t do something like `not( Foo( $s : barSet == testFunction() ) )` to be able to reuse the returned set `$s` on the RHS.